# Помощь по спавну и удалению объектов на Unity3D!

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Хочу создать игру с помощью Unity3D по типу динозаврика из google chrome только в 3d, движение игрока и прыжки я сделал, но как спавнить и удалять платформы так, чтобы не засорять игру(оптимизация) и не было такой проблемы, что объекты не успевают появляться и игрок падает в пустоту, я никак не могу реализовать.[image: Сама платформа]

Comment: Насколько я помню, в Unity принято не удалять объекты, а переиспользовать, потому что создание объектов много времени отнимает.

Comment: Можете помочь? Просто не могу никак придумать идею чтобы так сделать!

Comment: Вот тут вроде что-то на тему https://habr.com/ru/post/275091/ вообще погуглите по словам unity3d object pooling.

Comment: А возможно реализовать бесконечную платформу(как на беговой дорожке, платформа будет двигаться, а персонаж стоять), на которой будут только текстуры накладываться?

Comment: Да, конечно. Вообще посмотрите лучше на youtube видео таториалы от Гоши Дударя по Unity, он там и такую игру тоже показывает как делать, если ничего не путаю.

Comment: Я его смотрел, но вроде не видел ничего про раннеры, сейчас проверю...

Comment: Ну я у кого-то видел прям и динозаврика этого вроде. Может у кого-то другого. Больше не подскажу, читайте, смотрите, всё есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Гугл динозаврик в 3Д? Хауди Хо смотрели?

Ну если сделать совсем просто, то можно создать 2-3 платформы и поставить сзади динозаврика детектор (причем детектор прикрепить к динозаврику, чтобы когда бежал динозаврик двигался и детектор). Как только в детектор будет входить платформа он будет изменять устанавливать платформу на некотором расстоянии впереди игрока, в то время как сам игрок будет бежать по другой платформе. Обратите внимание, что именно менять позицию платфоры, а не удалять ее и впереди создавать другую, так как это затратнее.

Насчет вашего вопроса, можно ли двигать не динозаврика, а платформу, а динозарик стоит на месте: вообще можно, но я думаю, что это хуже, так как если помимо игрока и платформы будут и какие-то дополнительные элементы: враги (в оригинальной игре кактусы и птицы) или, например, какие-нибудь цветочки для красоты, то:

> Если динозаврик двигается, то игре придется всего лишь изменять позицию динозаврика и камеры (ну и детектора)

> Если платформа двигается, то игре придется просчитывать и изменять позиции вообще всех объектов на сцене: кактусов, растений и чего там у вас будет для красоты

P.S. Расстояние между динозавриком и детектором должно быть равно или даже чуть больше, чем длина одной платформы.
P.P.S. Периодически советую возвращать динозаврика ну нулевые координаты, чтобы его координаты не уходили в триллионы, но если вы сделаете сложную игру, то это не обязательно, так как вряд ли игроки смогут так долго не проигрывать.